# Can't upload files to OneDrive in modern view

Tags: 2016, modern-experience

This is an on-prem SharePoint 2016 server. Attempting to upload a file results in a status of "uploading 1 item" that never completes. This happens when using the upload button as well as dragging-dropping files into the library. After switching to classic mode via the "return to classic OneDrive" link at the bottom left, the upload works fine.

Uploading files to other libraries in SharePoint works fine, this issue is only impacting the OneDrive libraries, as far as I can tell.

Any suggestions of what to check for why the file upload doesn't work for OneDrive while in modern view?

Comment: did you also install [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3127942/november-8-2016-update-for-sharepoint-server-2016-kb3127942) after installing the feature pack 1 ? It is a prerequisite to ensure the modern experience works smoothly

Comment: Yes, both the language dependent and language independent updates were installed.

Comment: Does it work with the sync tool? [Sync Tool](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sync-sharepoint-files-with-the-new-onedrive-sync-client-6de9ede8-5b6e-4503-80b2-6190f3354a88)

Comment: Are there any exceptions or suspicious activity in ULS logs?

Comment: Did you check with the debugger window of the browser open. There might be some clientside exceptions.

Comment: No error, but the following call simply hangs and doesn't return: https://server.domain.com/personal/userid/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27%2Fpersonal%2Fuserid%2FDocuments%27)/Files?$filter=Name

Comment: I can't find anything at all in the logs re this issue. And the sync tool doesn't seem to be working, though it turns out it's also not working on the main libraries, so I don't know if there's some other issue there. (The sync may be a networking issue, I'll need to retest that later)